# Ethnoreligions: what religions explicitly claim heritability?

Tags: religion, genetics

Several SE/SO questions (e.g., [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/41901/race-is-to-racism-as-religion-is-to-what)) address what is often claimed to be (often correctly) confusion between ethnicity and religion. Certainly (IIUC, ICBW) most modern religions tend to be avowedly (pun intended :-) cognitive: they require acceptance of a body of beliefs and practices, but not (explicitly) a genetic link to coreligionists. However there are just as certainly religions (especially older ones) which traditionally explicitly assumed heritability, most notably [Judaism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Who_is_a_Jew%3F#Jewish_by_birth), which traditionally considered Jewishness matrilineal and discouraged conversion.

Hence I'd appreciate pointers to any work that has been done on this topic: what religions explicitly claim heritability? Are there any lists or taxonomies regarding the intersection of religion and ethnicity?

(Apologies if this is not the optimal Stack Exchange for this question: I note that there are several separate SEs for individual religions, but none for religion or religiousity in the aggregate.)

Comment: I'm afraid this isn't really on topic here. I agree that there isn't a site that's well suited to this question, but unfortunately we don't guarantee that every question is on topic somewhere.

Comment: [Welcome to Skeptics!](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1505/welcome-to-new-users) According to the [FAQ](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/faq#questions), Skeptics.SE is for researching the evidence behind the claims you hear or read. This question doesn't appear to have any doubtful claims to investigate. Please edit it to reference a notable claim and flag for moderator attention to re-open (or get 5 re-open votes).